# How to get OR pattern in Gorilla mux routing

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I'm trying to use Gorilla mux router to handle paths that respond to a limited list of strings in the URL. The service I am developing will take files from the caller and pass them through an "adapter" that send them to S3 or OneDrive, depending on the "adapter" specified in the URL. I also require a variable named "schema", which I only mention now because of the weirdness that follows. My test is as follows ({schema} will be set to "test"):

```
router.HandleFunc("/{adapter:(s3|onedrive)}/{schema:[a-z]+}/check",
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"a":"%s","s":"%s"}`,
        mux.Vars(r)["adapter"], mux.Vars(r)["schema"])))
}).Methods("GET")
```

I would expect that going to `/s3/test/check` would yield `{"a":"s3","s":"test"}` just as going to `/onedrive/test/check` should yield `{"a":"onedrive","s":"test"}` ... however in these cases I am getting `{"a":"s3","s":"s3"}` and `{"a":"onedrive","s":"onedrive"}` respectively.

The `(s3|onedrive)` check seems to be enforced because, for example, trying to go to `/dropbox/test/check` correctly yields a 404.

Why is the `{schema}` variable getting the value of the `{adapter}` variable and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of parenthesis which denote capturing group and yield submatch. It can interfere with gorilla matcher. Just try without parenthesis.

```
router.HandleFunc("/{adapter:s3|onedrive}/{schema:[a-z]+}/check",
```